# jQuery selector for document and another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can I merge these in jQuery? I'm using the HotKeys plugin.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'n', cycleNoise);
$(document).bind('keydown', 's', pickRandom);
$(document).bind('keydown', 'v', toggleTasks);
$(document).bind('keydown', 't', toggleTimer);
$(document).bind('keydown', 'up', hideTask);
$(document).bind('keydown', 'down', nextTask);
$('#duration').bind('keydown', 't', toggleTimer);
$('#duration').bind('keydown', 'n', cycleNoise);
$('#duration').bind('keydown', 's', pickRandom);
$('#duration').bind('keydown', 'v', toggleTasks);
$('#duration').bind('keydown', 'up', hideTask);
$('#duration').bind('keydown', 'down', nextTask);
```

In other words, is it possible to use `document` and `'#duration'` in the same selector. The following doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document + ',#duration').bind(...);
```

**EDIT**:

I am using the [jQuery HotKeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js) plugin. This prevents bubbling from text fields by design. Can I disable this feature *just for this specific textbox* by modifying the source? If so, please let me know how.

Also does the plugin merge the keydown events or is it really attaching 12 separate handlers? I don't understand jQuery well enough to work it out. What's the best solution to achieve the desired effect (acting on the hotkeys, except when in textboxes - apart from in `'#duration'` where the hotkeys should be bound).

Comment: Oh my God, the code repetition... my eyes... `:P`

Comment: Note that from jQuery 1.7 onward, you can (and should) replace .bind() with .on(). I believe the syntax will remain unchanged, but you should look at the docs to confirm. You can pass multiple events to a single selector with .on() (and I believe .bind() as well).

Comment: @James I don't get this... Why do you bind six handlers to the `keydown` event? (All six handles will be invoked on *every* `keydown` event.)

Comment: I guess he thinks that it would only trigger if the specific key is pressed. At least according to the jQuery docs this isn't the case though...

Comment: @James The plug-in makes sure that only the intended callback is invoked... (without the plug-in, *all* callbacks would be invoked on every `keydown` event...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$( [ document, input ] ).
    keydown( 'n', cycleNoise ).
    keydown( 's', pickRandom ).
    keydown( 'v', toggleTasks ).
    keydown( 't', toggleTimer ).
    keydown( 'up', hideTask ).
    keydown( 'down', nextTask );
```

where `input` is a reference to your INPUT element. In this case:

```
var input = $( '#duration' )[0];
```

---

Another solution is

```
$( '#duration' ).add( document ). // etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

This should also work,

```
var keys = {
    'n': cycleNoise,
    's': pickRandom,
    ....
    ..
    ..
}

$.each(keys, function(key, callback) {
    $(document).add("#duration").bind('keydown', key, callback);
})
```

Also consider ThiefMaster answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('body ,#duration').bind(...);
```

Actually, if you bind to the document there is no need to bind to anything else.

As others have pointed out, your keydown bind syntax is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to event bubbling an event handler bound to the document itself will receive all events - so you can simply remove the `$('#duration')` events.

Your handlers will trigger for **all** keys btw, you cannot restrict them - you need to check which key was pressed using `e.which` (assuming the first parameter of the handler function is named `e`) in the function itself.